# Set array using psql interface

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a function that adds users to the database from an array, e.g.

```
psql -c "SELECT addUsersFromList(array['userA','userB','userC'])"
```

This works fine, however I would prefer to be able to run this as a script, like so:

```
psql -f add_users.sql -v userlist=array['userA','userB','userC'])
```

And add_user.sql:

```
SELECT addUsersFromList(:userlist);
```

When I execute the above psql command, I get an error:

```
psql:Scripts/add_users.sql:39: ERROR:  column "userA" does not exist
```

This seems to be an issue with how I use the -v flag. I had a look at the [postgres documentaion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) on -v, \set and the Variables section on that same page, but could not find a way to assign an array.

Comment: Your shell is probably removing the single quotes. You need to escape them somehow, probably combining multiple levels of quoting

Comment: As said , your shell is removing those quotes. `psql -f add_users.sql -v "userlist=array['userA','userB','userC']"` should work (you could also escape those single quotes instead but this way is easier IMO). You can also use `\echo :userlist` (inside a `psql` shell) to see what `userlist` was set to/read as.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed removing the single quotes. Surrounding this with double quotes works well and is easy to do! Both surrounding everything as you suggested or just the array part. Would you like to submit this as an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the array as a string literal:

```sh
psql -f add_users.sql -v "userlist='{userA,userB,userC}'"
```